# Made me abreast?

Tags: word-choice, diction

Background: I had spoken to Person A on the phone, and he caught me up with the happenings of Person B.

Is it correct to tell Person B that "he [Person A] made me abreast of what was going on with you [Person B]"?

If not, what's a better choice? I don't want to say "informed" me, as that is too formal sounding.

Comment: It's correct, as another example (from Googling!), **It further made her abreast of the end consumer's need.**. However, I prefer to use another choice, such as  : 'I assure you, Mr Swan,' he said eventually, 'that I **made him aware of the conflict of interest** we may face if you and/or Miss Banner are charged.

Comment: It's idiomatically at the very least *unusual* phrasing - normally we say [*to **put** him abreast (of the current state of some changing situation)*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+put+him+abreast%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). That version gets 17 hits on Google Books, whereas *to **make** him abreast* gets none at all. Informal alternatives (apart from the screamingly obvious *He **told** me **about** it*) include *He **filled me in on** the current situation*.

Comment: 'kept me abreast' is actually a little _more_ formal than 'informed'.

Comment: I think "bring abreast" would be more idiomatic than "make abreast".

Comment: ***apprised***, was informal not requisite here.

Comment: I saw the title and thought of this scene from the Simpsons: http://www.truetranssoulrebel.com/wp-content/uploads/krustyboobs.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Some time spent with the google, including the Ngram viewer, finds that "made abreast" is a rare locution.  It is idiomatic to say "brought me abreast" or "kept me abreast."  The former is mostly used for physical proximity; the latter, to mean "kept informed."

Comment: Quite a satisfactory answer and kudos on "locution".

Answer (score 3):

One more option for a replacement phrasing is "(bring) up to speed":

> Jim ***brought me up to speed*** about what's going on with you.

From [freedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+speed):

> 2. ***up to speed*** on someone or something *Fig.* fully apprised about someone or something; up-to-date on the state of someone or something. *(*Typically: be ~; bring someone ~; get ~; get someone ~.)*
>
>    > "Please bring me up to speed on this matter."
>    >     "I'll feel better about it when I get up to speed on what's going on."

Answer (score 2):

You say that you don't want to be too formal but any sentence with 'abreast of' sounds formal (and a little dated) to me.

My suggestion,

> I spoke to  A on the phone, and he brought me up to date with the happenings of B.

or

> I spoke to  A on the phone, and he updated me on the happenings of B.

Answer (score 1):

It's technically correct, without being exactly colloquial and just generally, 'abreast' used like that can lend itself to some puns on mammary lines.

Also, 'abreast' is a word that relates to news, current events and professional matters (eg the latest orthodontic techniques), rather more than say, personal matters.  'Abreast' suggests that the events concerning Person B are in the public arena, in the Kardashian sense.

It would be safer to say "he brought me up to date", "he let me know" or even "he updated me" - depends on how sensitive the information is.

If you are talking to a third person, not person B, you have rather more colourful options to use, such as "marked my card" or "had a word in my ear" (you will even hear, "had a word in my shell-like" (= ear).  These are a bit gossipy.

Comment: Puns?  You mean like the secretary who was suspected of enhancing her profile with paper products -- she was "keeping a breast of the Times".  (Nah, nothing as bad as that!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you normally "keep abreast" rather than "make abreast" so you could say:

> I have been kept abreast of what B is doing.

(However that suggests an ongoing interest in B).

---

Or for a one-time phone call:

> I have spoken to A, who has been keeping me abreast of what B was doing.